# Durandal multi step, non linear wizard - compose and router questions

Tags: durandal

[Wizard 2](http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-2.0/#master-detail/wizard2) is a great example and has helped my understanding immensely, thank you @RainerAtSpirit.

### We build wizards that dynamically select the next step

The software that I'm working on uses a lot of wizards, in elegant ways. Some of the wizards are non-linear and some also have circular flows where information can be incrementally added before finally submitted. The current code is okay but I believe would benefit by moving to durandal.

### The router is very close to what I need, I just don't need the url bit

Durandal's built-in router would be a great way to implement a non-linear wizard - each wizard step could specify an href of the next step, and normal composition would take over. However in my use case there is limited reason to be able to bookmark or navigate to a particular wizard step through the url. Additionally the wizard keeps too much information pending, a url would not be enough to get back to a correct wizard state. Wizards are often displayed in modal dialogs which I believe illustrates their use case in our system - a workflow with an eventual action on the system.

### Does something like this already exist?

If a pattern like this already exists in durandal, or someone already has an example to share that would be much appreciated. I suspect I will need to build something specific. For the rest of the question I will detail my current thoughts on how to implement it nicely.

### If I had to build it myself this is what I would do, am I on the right track?

The compose binding is almost perfect for my needs however I need a way for a 'sub' view model to provide instructions to it's containing wizard view model to change to another step and optionally provide data to pass to the new view model.

E.g. When using a router any href="#location" gets picked up by the router and selects a new view model which is then composed into the binding dom element by data-bind="router: ..." I'd like similar functionality just skipping over the whole url part.

I was thinking about setting up a binding hander for data-bind="wizard: ..." and data-bind="wizardnext: 'steps/two'". The wizard binding would be a wrapper of 'compose:' and be in charge of transitioning between wizard steps, the wizardnext binding would load up a new view model and transition the wizard to the new content. My question is, how would the wizardnext binding handler find out which wizard the view model is currently within? Is there a way to get a handle on the tree of view models, search down the tree from the current view model until a wizard is found then interact with that wizard? I don't want to use a global because I imagine it might be possible to have two wizards on the page at once.

Instead of a knockout binding handler my other options for the wizard are a normal view model, or a widget however I don't think they quite match my needs. Either way I want a way for internal view models to talk to the container so I can change the compose to a new view model.

[This google groups discussion suggest three options](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/durandaljs/kGZSqT-4GBU/gezfPthJQVAJ) however they all make sense if implemented within the actual application's code. If I'm trying to make a reusable component I don't know what the data looks like.

Solutions I'm hoping to hear:

Yes this is already supported, just do X Y Z
Yes, there is a way to have the wizardstep get a reference to the wizard binding / view model
Yes, there is a way to have the wizard get a reference to all wizardsteps within it's context

Thoughts?

Comment: I could use pub sub (http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Leveraging-Publish-Subscribe/) however I still need to know which event a specific wizard should subscribe to - there may be more than one wizard on the page at once.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using compose with activation data to pass in a reference to the wizard into each step through the activate method. This way each step can implement it's own forward and back buttons, either by calling the wizard directly through a click binding or through it's own click binding.

Seems to work well.

```
wizard.html:
<div data-bind="compose: { model: current, activationData: $data }"></div>

wizard.js:
wizard.prototype.current = ko.observable('');
wizard.prototype.next = function(view) { return function() { this.current(view); } };

step1.js:
step1.prototype.activate = function(wizard) { this.wizard = wizard; }

step1.html:
<a data-bind="click: wizard.next('views/wizard/step2')" href="#">Next</a>
```